# If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is Entire and $\vert f \vert\le A+B\vert z \vert^{3/2}$, then $f$ is Linear

Tags: complex-analysis

I am given that $$\vert f \vert\le A+B\vert z \vert^{3/2}$$
and I would like to show that $f$ is a linear polynomial. A generalization of *Liouville's Theorem* says that if $\vert f\vert\le C\vert z \vert^k$ for some positive integer $k$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$. Since there is a power of $3/2$, this fact doesn't immediately apply. So we can write $\vert fz^{1/2}\vert\le D\vert z^2\vert$ for $\vert z \vert>R$ for some sufficiently large $R$.

Hence $fz^{1/2}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$. Say, $fz^{1/2}=a+bz+cz^2$ ($c$ may be $0$). Then $f=az^{-1/2}+bz^{1/2}+cz^{3/2}$, which is not a linear polynomial for two reasons (it's not a polynomial in $z$ and it's not linear in $z$). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $z^{1/2}$ is not an entire function (it has a branch cut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You don't quite have the hypothesis right for the "generalization of Liouville's Theorem".  First show $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.  Then show the coefficient of $z^2$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You also could just reprove the lemma you are using in a more general version. You could use Cauchy’s formula.
\begin{align}
|f^{(2)} (z)| &= \Big| \frac{2!}{2πi} \int_{rγ} \frac{f(w)}{(w - z)^3} dw \Big| \\
&≤ C·r·\max \Big\{\frac{A}{|w - z|^3} + \frac{B·|w|^{3/2}}{|w - z|^3}; w ∈ rγ\Big\}\\
&≤ \frac{C'}{\sqrt r},
\end{align}
where $γ\colon [0..1] → ℂ~,t ↦ \mathrm{e}^{it}$. As $r$ is arbitrary, $f^{(2)} = 0$, so …

Edit: Fixed a mistake. The last inequality is actually a little bit more work.